# Radio Button Visibility

Tags: jquery

On the click of a button, how can i make all the hidden radio buttons show up? Simplest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type="radio"]).show();
```

Comment: you're missing a single quote at the end of the selector string

Answer (score 3):

This is a really naive and easy way to do it, depends how you're hiding your radio buttons I guess.

```
$("input[type='radio']").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are hiding them with CSS `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` you can do the following:

```
$('#buttonID').click(function (){
     $('input:radio').css('display', 'block'); //or css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

It would help if you tell us more about the way they are hidden.

Cheers!